# find subjects that have value <2 for any sample and also >=2 for any other sample

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame of subjects with samples and the concentrations in those samples.  What I want is to get a vector of the **subjects** that have a conc <2 for any sample and also >=2 for any other sample for that same subj.

```
ex <- data.frame(subj = rep(1:6, each = 2), 
           sampleID =  1:12, 
           conc = c(1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 3.2, 3.3, 1.6, 2.7, 2.8, 1.4, NA, NA, 3.9))
```

It's easy enough to find the subj that have a conc <2 in any sample:

```
ex %>%                  # conc < 2
   filter(conc < 2) %>% 
   print() %>% 
   distinct(subj) %>% 
   summarise( n())
```

But what I need is to find subj that have conc <2 in any sample and that also have a conc >=2 in any other sample within that same patient. This is what I have so far, but it *doesn't work*. The correct answer is only two subjects (#2 and #3) have conc both <2 and also >=2.

```
ex %>%                  # concs < 2 and also > 2 for each subject
   mutate(lt = ifelse(.$conc < 2, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
   mutate(ge = ifelse(.$conc >= 2, TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
   group_by(subj)  %>% 
   summarise( xor(any(.$lt), any(.$ge)))
```

I strongly prefer a solution that uses dplyr with magrittr pipes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
ex %>%
  group_by(subj) %>%
  filter(any(conc < 2) & any(conc >=2))
```

Note: This returns the full set. If you want just the subjects, you could modify it to:

```
ex %>%
  group_by(subj) %>%
  filter(any(conc < 2) & any(conc >=2)) %>%
  distinct(subj) %>%
  select(subj)
```

If you want to be more verbose, you could do something like this:

```
less_than_2 <- ex %>%
  group_by(subj) %>%
  filter(conc < 2)

greater_than_or_2 <- ex %>%
  group_by(subj) %>%
  filter(conc >= 2)

intersect(less_than_2$subj, greater_than_or_2$subj)
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks. This was flummoxing me for quite a while

Answer (score 2):

Not dplyr, but with data.table:

```
setDT(ex)[, .(select = any(conc < 2) & any(conc >=2)), by=subj]
```

Returns:

```
   subj select
1:    1  FALSE
2:    2   TRUE
3:    3   TRUE
4:    4  FALSE
5:    5     NA
6:    6     NA
```

If you want just the values of subj where the `select` vector is TRUE:

```
setDT(ex)[, .(select = any(conc < 2) & any(conc >=2)), by=subj][
  select==T, subj]
```

You can add `na.rm=T` to the `any` calls if you want to remove NA values.

Comment: Standard version of the second one would look like `if (cond) .SD, by=subj`

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me if you want to keep the original data frame and add a marker for the subjects that meet your criteria or filter down to the ones that meet them. If the latter, Jason's answer has you covered. If the former, you could do:

```
ex %>%
  group_by(subj) %>%
  summarise(test = min(conc) < 2 & max(conc) >= 2) %>%
  left_join(ex, .)
```